# How to give validation to radio buttons before page redirect to contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have developed a survey form with the help of html and css. I want to give validation to question before page redirect to Contact form. In Survey form when user click in submit button page will redirect to contact form.
but i want to put validation so that user has to click on all question before page redirect to contact form.

Comment: just to use required in your code `<input type="radio" name="question1" value="A" required >`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the privalage to comment but you can use the required field as follows

```
 <input type="radio" name="question-1-answers" id="question-1-answers-A" value="A" required=true />
```

using this way the user will have to click all the required fields before submitting a form.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure all fields are filled before submission of the form:

```
<input type="radio" required>
```

The ' required ' attribute makes sure all fields are filled before the form can be submitted.

Comment: hi , i want to add validation on question not on radio (options),

Comment: please help how i can get these value in database.

Comment: What do you mean by 'validation on question'?
To get them into a database, you need to send them back to your server and store it in a database from there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the required-attribute for one input of the radiogroup, but you can set it for all.

use the required field validator or refer the link below http://www.chennaisunday.com/jsradio.html